# Comparing 2 arrays to find out if they have the same elements or not

Tags: c

I'm a beginner programmer and i needed some help with an exercise! As you saw in the title the exercise asks to write a program that compares the elements of 2 arrays to find out if they have the same elements or not. The trick is that the elements on the 2nd array may not be in the same order as the ones in the first array.
I thought that maybe one way to fix this is to rearrange the 2 arrays for them to be in ascending order but for some reason it keeps saying that the arrays have the same elements. Can you help me?

This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int v[N];
    int v2[N];
    int i,j;
    int a;
    int b;
    int flag = 0;

    printf("Please enter the values of the 1st array: ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<N; j++)
        {
            if(v[i]>v[j])
            {
                a = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter the values of the 2nd array: ");
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (v2[i] > v2[j])
            {
                b = v2[i];
                v2[i] = v2[j];
                v2[j] = b;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (v[i] == v2[j])
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1)
        printf("\nThe arrays have the same numbers! ");
    else
        printf("\nThe arrays dont have the same numbers!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is never a good problem description. What errors or incorrect behaviour are you getting? And have you done any basic debugging to answer basic questions such as are the input arrays correct, is the sorted array correct, are the right values being compared, etc? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Ok i changed the text. The problem is that it keeps saying that the arrays have the same elements unless the 3 elements are completely different. If even one of them is the same it says that they have the same elemets

Comment: And how about the debugging? Have you done any basic debugging? Note that just running the program is not debugging (that's testing). Step thru the code in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements to trace the program flow and variable values to find out where things first go wrong.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you are sorting these arrays if you are checking every element of the first array against every element of the second array anyway. This makes the sorting just a waste of time

Comment: That's the thing. I have tried to find where the problem may lie, In my head according to what i think ,i did it right. I take one element from the 1st array and compare it with all the elements of the 2nd array and if it matches i set the flag to 1 and move to the 2nd element and so on. The problem is most deffinitely at how i wrote the comparison but i cant figure out how to write it correctly.

Comment: @UnholySheep I was getting annoyed because i couldnt figure out how to do it and i thought that maybe that might help. I know that it is a waste but that was all i could think

Comment: Well, if you insist on keeping the sorting in there you should really make use of it by simplifying the check to check that the elements at the same indices in both arrays are the same (so something like `v[i] == v2[i]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting loops seem correct, but the comparison loop is not: you compare every item from the first array to every item of the second array, so the result will be true if any number of the first array is present in the second array, which is a much weaker condition.

You should use a much simpler comparison loop, comparing `v[i]` and `v2[i]` for `i` varying from `0` to `N` excluded.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N  100

int main() {
    int v[N];
    int v2[N];
    int i, j;
    int flag;

    printf("Please enter the values of the 1st array: ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                int a = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter the values of the 2nd array: ");
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v2[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (v2[i] > v2[j]) {
                int b = v2[i];
                v2[i] = v2[j];
                v2[j] = b;
            }
        }
    }

    flag = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (v[i] != v2[i]) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1)
        printf("\nThe arrays have the same numbers! ");
    else
        printf("\nThe arrays dont have the same numbers!");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative algorithm with the same time complexity, but without modifying the arrays: for each element of array `v`, if both arrays have the same number of copies, continue else the arrays are different.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N  100

int count(const int *v, int len, int x) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        n += (v[i] == x);
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int v[N];
    int v2[N];
    int i;
    int flag;

    printf("Please enter the values of the 1st array: ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter the values of the 2nd array: ");
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &v2[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    flag = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (count(v, N, v[i]) != count(v2, N, v[i])) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1)
        printf("\nThe arrays have the same numbers! ");
    else
        printf("\nThe arrays dont have the same numbers!");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be other issues, but the main issue I see here is this:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        if(v[i]==v2[j])
        {
            flag=1;
        }
    }
}
```

What this is saying is for each element in the first array, check each element in the second array; if it is equal to the element in the first array, then set flag = 1. Essentially, it returns true if ANY of the elements are the same in the two arrays.

Comment: Then how would you suggest i do it?

Comment: When you're looking at the array elements, you want to check the same index in both arrays. Therefore, you should only be using one for loop with one variable. In that for loop, you'd check whether v[i] and v2[i] are the same, and if they are set flag equal to 1 and break out of the loop (if you don't know how to do that, it's fine; it's not required for the program to work properly, only to make it more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure all elements of the two arrays are the same, but you need to accommodate for them being in different orders, you could either sort them both and compare, or you could keep notes as you go.

You can create an array of ints with the same length as the arrays you're comparing, and use them as flags to check whether you've "used" an index in the second array when checking the elements in the first array.

We'll see this to all `0`, then as we scan the first array, we'll disregard any indices in the second array that have already been used. If we find a match, we'll set a flag to say that the index in array 2 has been used, and we'll break the inner loop to save ourselves any further iteration over the second array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int arrays_match(int *arr1, int *arr2, int n) {
    size_t used[n];

    /* Initialize the used array to all 0 or false. */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        used[i] = 0;    
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int in_both = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (used[j] == 0 && arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                in_both = 1;
                used[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!in_both) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int b[4] = { 4, 2, 3, 1 };

    if (arrays_match(a, b, 4)) {
        printf("Huzzah!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Huh?\n");
    }
}
```

This ends up printing "Huzzah!" but if we initialize `a` with `{ 4, 2, 2, 1 }` then it prints "Huh?"

Consider what happens when we run the below example.

```
a = { 1, 2, 4, 2 }
b = { 4, 2, 2, 1 }
used = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

The outer loop deals with `a[0]` first, which is `1`. It iterates through the inner loop until `j` is `3`, at which point it both finds a match, and `used[3]` is still `0`.

```
a = { 1, 2, 4, 2 }
b = { 4, 2, 2, 1 }
used = { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
```

Now the outer loop is checking `a[1]` which is `2`.  It checks `b` until it gets to `b[1]` and `used[1]` is `0`, so it finds a match.

```
a = { 1, 2, 4, 2 }
b = { 4, 2, 2, 1 }
used = { 0, 1, 0, 1 }
```

Next the outer loop is checking `a[2]` which is `4`.  It checks `b` until it gets to `b[0]` and `used[0]` is `0`, so it finds a match.

```
a = { 1, 2, 4, 2 }
b = { 4, 2, 2, 1 }
used = { 1, 1, 0, 1 }
```

Finally the outer loop is checking `a[3]` which is again `2`.  It checks `b` until it gets to `b[1]` which is also `2`, but `used[1]` is `1`, so it can't find a match here. It continues on to `b[2]` and finds a match because `used[2]` is still `0`.

```
a = { 1, 2, 4, 2 }
b = { 4, 2, 2, 1 }
used = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
```

It's reached the end of the iteration and no mismatches have been detected. The function returns 1 (true).